# Remove substring in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column has strings that sometimes contain a word and parentheses around the value I want to keep. How do I do remove them? Here's what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Espacios_@cronista.csv")
del df['Espacio']

df[df['Tamano'].str.contains("Variable")]
```

Output I have:

```
         Tamano              Subastas  Imp         Fill_rate  
0        Variable (300x600)  43        13          5.99   
1        Variable (266x600)  43        5           4.44  
2        266x600             43        5           4.44
```

Output I need:

```
   Tamano  Subastas  Imp         Fill_rate  
0   300x600  43      13          5.99   
1   266x600  43      5           4.44   
2   266x600  43      5           4.44
```

Comment: Please, check again... @Tai

Comment: how does it look like the data in the .csv?

Comment: as in the example of the output but with the `df['Espacio'`@KnocktoriusMaxima

Comment: so you have: `Variable (300x600)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good use case for [**`pd.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

**pipelined**
Meaning, `assign` creates a copy.  You can use `fillna` to fill in spots that became `NaN`.

```
pat = 'Variable\s*\((.*)\)'
df.assign(Tamano=df.Tamano.str.extract(pat, expand=False).fillna(df.Tamano))

    Tamano  Subastas  Imp  Fill_rate
0  300x600        43   13       5.99
1  266x600        43    5       4.44
2  266x600        43    5       4.44
```

---

**in place**
Meaning we alter `df`

```
pat = 'Variable\s*\((.*)\)'
df.update(df.Tamano.str.extract(pat, expand=False))
df

    Tamano  Subastas  Imp  Fill_rate
0  300x600        43   13       5.99
1  266x600        43    5       4.44
2  266x600        43    5       4.44
```

Comment: Only detail, if I have another value as the only the number now I have `NaN` row and I need the old value...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  It would be better to edit your question if it doesn't change the scope too much.  Otherwise, finalize this question and write a new question with additional details.

Comment: Updated.  Mind that the in place option is the same.  There are lots of ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, this should work

```
cond = df.Tamano.str.contains("Variable")
df.loc[cond, "Tamano"] = df.Tamano.str.extract("((?<=\()[^)]*)", expand=False)

Tamano  Subastas    Imp Fill_rate
0   300x600 43  13  5.99
1   266x600 43  5   4.44
2   266x600 43  5   4.44
```

This will select the rows fit the condition: `df.Tamano.str.contains("Variable")` to do replacement. The regular expression `(?<=\()` means will look for `(` and match what is behind. The matching criterion `[^)]*` is to match any that is not `)`, and thus will stop when meeting a `)`. piRSquared's regular expression is more simple and easy to understand.